# Анимация текста как на фото

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animation

Как можно реализовать такую анимацию текста как на ссылке: https://timochko.ru/

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Заранье СПАСИБО**

Comment: данный вопрос в виде картинки следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний (тот, у кого возникнет подобный вопрос, не сможет найти данный вопрос и ответы к нему)

Answer (score 2):

Пример

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background-color: #000;
    padding: 2rem;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

h1 {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 8vw;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    overflow: hidden;
}

h1::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 10vw;
    height: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 90vw rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
    filter: blur(10px);
    animation: animTextBg 15s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes animTextBg {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(0);
    }

    100% {
        transform: translateX(100vw);
    }
}
```

```html
<h1>Старт в запусках</h1>
```